# How to set NODE_ENV variable in elasticbeanstalk optionsettings file

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need to set it in the eb option settings file, not the console.  I don't understand why the following code from .elasticbeanstalk/optionsettings.myappEnv doesn't work.  I've poured over the aws doc and stack overflow to no avail.

```
[aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment]
PARAM1=
PARAM2=
PARAM3=
PARAM4=
PARAM5=
NODE_ENV=production
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so I gave up on the option settings file and created an env.config file with the following in it:

option_settings:
  - option_name: NODE_ENV
    value: production

That worked fine. I'm using the aws eb command line tools. Complete contents of env.config under .ebextensions folder:

```
packages: 
  yum:
    ImageMagick: [] 

option_settings:
  - option_name: NODE_ENV
    value: production


commands:
  000_fixNpmHome:
    command: sed -i 's/function error_exit/export HOME=\/root\n\nfunction error_exit/' /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/50npm.sh
  010_fixNpmProduction:
    command: sed -i "s/'install'/'install', '--production'/" /opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I remember seeing something about env.config in the docs, could you reference that to me? Or tell me where to put env.config and how to sync it with my existing instance?

Comment: I have not been able to get this working yet. I'm assuming you've set it so that `app.get('env')` returns `production`? I've setup a .ebextensions/env.config with the following `option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
    option_name: NODE_ENV
    value: production` but have gotten it to work yet. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, app.get('env') returns production.  I don't have the namespace: key in mine, not sure you need that or not.  here is the link to where i found the solution:  https://github.com/giggio/atelies/blob/master/.ebextensions/020_environment.config

Comment: Hm. thanks for the update. That still doesn't work for me. Here's my gist, https://gist.github.com/MichaelCastelbuono/7605911 for my option settings. Do I need the other commands you have? Also, when saving the .config file, all I should need to do is run `eb update` right?

Comment: Wow, no clue.  That looks right to me.  FWIW i found the aws docs scattered and lacking.  Sorry about that, hope you can get it working.

Comment: I got it working and am shamed to say I had just not committed the .config file to my repo :( I thought `eb` took care of options and what not, but you actually do have to `git commit ./ebextensions/*` and can then `git aws.push` or deploy via the web console. Should be obvious, but worth noting in case someone else has this problem.